# Excel VBA - Hide Rows for Print Job - Working for some but not all Variables

Tags: vba, excel, rows, hidden

this is my first time posting on this site and I am fairly new to VBA. I tried to find the answer online but couldn't find an appropriate solution.

I am trying to hide certain rows and columns just for printing and then I want the vba code to unhide the same rows/columns. The columns are always the same so figuring that out was easy enough but I am struggling with the rows. I figured out how to hide rows with a blank cell in column A, which addresses half of the rows I want hidden but not all of them. I also want to hide any rows where the cell in column A equals:

- "BEER"
- "WINE"
- "LIQUOR"
- "N/A BEV"
- "INSERT NEW PRODUCTS BELOW THIS ROW"
- "INSERT NEW PRODUCTS ABOVE THIS ROW"
- "TOTAL C.O.G.   (AVERAGE)"

The code I have works for BEER, WINE, LIQUOR, and N/A BEV, but it does not work for the longer sentences. Please note that the rows containing these values will change over time so I cannot just list rows I want to hide like I did for columns.

Can someone point me in the right direction to make these rows hide as well? Here's the code:

```
Sub WorkbookBeforePrint_Called()

  Dim rw As Long
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    With rng.Columns(1)
         For Each cell In rng
             If .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value = "INSERT NEW PRODUCTS BELOW THIS ROW" Then _
             Parent.Rows(cell.Row).Hidden = True
             If .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value = "INSERT NEW PRODUCTS ABOVE THIS ROW" Then _
             .Parent.Rows(cell.Row).Hidden = True
             If .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value = "TOTAL C.O.G.   (AVERAGE)" Then _
             .Parent.Rows(cell.Row).Hidden = True
             If .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value = "BEER" Then _
             .Parent.Rows(cell.Row).Hidden = True
             If .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value = "WINE" Then _
             .Parent.Rows(cell.Row).Hidden = True
             If .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value = "LIQUOR" Then _
             .Parent.Rows(cell.Row).Hidden = True
             If .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value = "N/A BEV" Then _
             .Parent.Rows(cell.Row).Hidden = True
         Next cell

With ActiveSheet

    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=3
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=3
          .Range("C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1,M1,N1,O1,P1,Q1,R1,V1,W1,X1,Y1,Z1,AA1,AE1,AF1,AG1,AH1,AI1,AJ1,AN1,AO1,AP1,AQ1,AR1,AS1,AW1,AX1,AY1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

  On Error Resume Next
      .Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True

      .PrintOut

      .Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = False
  On Error GoTo 0
          .Range("C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1,M1,N1,O1,P1,Q1,R1,V1,W1,X1,Y1,Z1,AA1,AE1,AF1,AG1,AH1,AI1,AJ1,AN1,AO1,AP1,AQ1,AR1,AS1,AW1,AX1,AY1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=3
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=3

End With

    .EntireRow.Hidden = False

End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure the longer text strings font have newline characters in them?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I check?

Comment: All of the cells have the text on line one without out any leading spaces. I copied and paste the longer text into the code but it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps adding `debug.print .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value` will shed some light on the true value of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Any time that I have trouble like this, I try to eliminate transposition errors using text functions. Try adding the LEFT function like the example below.

```
If Left(.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value, 25) = "INSERT NEW PRODUCTS BELOW" Then _
            Rows(cell.Row).Hidden = True
```

If you would like, you can also capture both of those long strings using the same IF statement.

```
If Left(.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value, 19) = "INSERT NEW PRODUCTS" Then _
            Rows(cell.Row).Hidden = True
```

It's working for me with a sample data set but let me know if that helps you with the real data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different approach.  It's just the hiding part.

**Using Select Case instead of IF**

```
Sub WorkbookBeforePrint2()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sheet As String
Dim tempVal As String

    sheet = "Sheet1"    'Insert your sheet name here

    lastRow = Sheets(sheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For lRow = 2 To lastRow
        tempVal = Sheets(sheet).Cells(lRow, "A").Text
        Select Case tempVal
            Case Is = ""
                Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
            Case Is = "INSERT NEW PRODUCTS BELOW THIS ROW"
                Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
            Case Is = "INSERT NEW PRODUCTS ABOVE THIS ROW"
                Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
            Case Is = "TOTAL C.O.G.   (AVERAGE)"
                Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
            Case Is = "BEER"
                Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
            Case Is = "WINE"
                Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
            Case Is = "LIQUOR"
                Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
            Case Is = "N/A BEV"
                Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
        End Select
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

[image: BEFORE]
[image: AFTER]

Comment: I didn't write "TOTAL C.O.G.    (AVERAGE)". I left out the (AVERAGE) by mistake.  That is why it wasn't hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help everyone! I had the longer text variables included in the groups/oulines but not the shorter text variables. I simply needed to re-arrange the code:

```
Sub WorkbookBeforePrint(control As IRibbonControl)

  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim tempVal As String

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet

      ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=3
      ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=3

        .Range("C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1,M1,N1,O1,P1,Q1,R1,V1,W1,X1,Y1,Z1,AA1,AE1,AF1,AG1,AH1,AI1,AJ1,AN1,AO1,AP1,AQ1,AR1,AS1,AW1,AX1,AY1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

          For lRow = 2 To lastRow
            tempVal = .Cells(lRow, "A").Text
              Select Case tempVal
                Case Is = ""
                  Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
                Case Is = "INSERT NEW PRODUCTS BELOW THIS ROW"
                  Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
                Case Is = "INSERT NEW PRODUCTS ABOVE THIS ROW"
                  Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
                Case Is = "TOTAL C.O.G.   (AVERAGE)"
                  Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
                Case Is = "BEER"
                  Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
                Case Is = "WINE"
                  Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
                Case Is = "LIQUOR"
                  Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
                Case Is = "N/A BEV"
                  Rows(lRow).Hidden = True
              End Select
          Next lRow

      .PrintOut

        Rows(lRow).Hidden = False

        .Range("C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1,M1,N1,O1,P1,Q1,R1,V1,W1,X1,Y1,Z1,AA1,AE1,AF1,AG1,AH1,AI1,AJ1,AN1,AO1,AP1,AQ1,AR1,AS1,AW1,AX1,AY1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

      ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=3
      ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels ColumnLevels:=3

    End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```